# Farey Sequence implemenatation

Tags: fractions, continued-fractions, farey-sequences

I'm trying to use the Farey sequence to get the next lowest reduced fraction in a list. For example, for $n = 8$, we have $\dots, \frac13, \frac38, \frac25, \frac37, \frac12, \dots$

So let's take $\frac38$ and $\frac25$ and attempt to get $\frac37$.

$p = \left\lfloor\dfrac{n+b}{d}\right\rfloor c - a$

$q = \left\lfloor\dfrac{n+b}{d}\right\rfloor d - b$

$a=3, b=8, c=2, d=5, n=8$

$p = [\frac{8+8}{5}] \cdot 2 - 3$

$q = [\frac{8+8}{5}] \cdot 5 - 8$

$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{3.4}{8} \neq \frac37$

Am I using the equation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your equations, you have to take the floor of $\frac{n+b}{d}$. In your example, it's $\left\lfloor\frac{8+8}{5} \right\rfloor = 3$. Your $p$ is then $(3 \cdot 2) - 3 = 3$, and your $q$ is $(3 \cdot 5) - 8 = 7$.

Comment: Completely missed the floor. I was seeing brackets. Thank you.